# Making Vote System Secure Meteor.Methods

Tags: meteor, meteor-methods

I am trying to implement a voting system which is secure and cant be changed with a Meteor.call() from the client console. Everyone is able to vote some posts up and down if they are logged in. But just once a time for every user and post.

Ony my client side ive got something like this:

```
Template.postArgument.events({
 'click .yes':function() {
       if(Meteor.user()) {
        var postId = Arguments.findOne({_id:this._id})
        var currentArgumentId = this._id;
        if($.inArray(Meteor.userId(), postId.votedUp) ===-1) {
          if($.inArray(Meteor.userId(), postId.votedDown) !==-1) {
            Meteor.call('argumentVoteYes',currentArgumentId);
          } else {
            Meteor.call('argumentVoteYesElse',currentArgumentId);
          } 
        } else {
          Meteor.call('argumentVoteYesElseElse',currentArgumentId);
        }
      }
    }}
)};
```

On my Server:

```
    Meteor.methods({
    'argumentVoteYes':function(currentArgumentId){
        Arguments.update(currentArgumentId, {
            $pull: {votedDown: Meteor.userId()},
            $inc: {score: 2 },
                $addToSet: {votedUp: Meteor.userId() }
              });
      },
      'argumentVoteYesElse':function(currentArgumentId){
        Arguments.update(currentArgumentId, {
            $inc: {score: 1 },
            $addToSet: {votedUp: Meteor.userId() }
              });
      },
      'argumentVoteYesElseElse':function(currentArgumentId){
        Arguments.update(currentArgumentId, {
            $inc: {score: -1 },
            $pull: {votedUp: Meteor.userId()}
            });
      }
    'argumentVoteNo':function(currentArgumentId){
    Arguments.update(currentArgumentId, {
        $pull: {votedUp: Meteor.userId()},
        $inc: {score: -2 },
        $addToSet: {votedDown: Meteor.userId() },
        });
  },
  'argumentVoteNoElse':function(currentArgumentId){
    Arguments.update(currentArgumentId, {
        $inc: {score: -1 },
        $addToSet: {votedDown: Meteor.userId() },
        });

  },
  'argumentVoteNoElseElse':function(currentArgumentId){
    Arguments.update(currentArgumentId, {
        $inc: {score: 1 },
        $pull: {votedDown: Meteor.userId()}
        }); 
  },
    });
```

The question is how do i get this secure for example if someone calls a `Meteor.call('argumentvoteYes', "someID" , {$inc: {score:2}});` It will increment the score of 2. If a user is calling this twice the vote will increment 4. Is there any way doing this a secure way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about an extra increment coming in to the method since your methods only accept a single parameter. However you do need to guard against other hacks:

Let's first extend the `Match` object so that we can check that an `_id` is just that:

```
Match._id = Match.Where(function(id){
  check(id, String); // first make sure we're dealing with a string
  // then grep for an exactly 17 character alphanumeric string
  return /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{17,17}/.test(id); 
});
```

[more on this technique](http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/12/meteor-security-no-4-extending-match.html)

Now let's take your first method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'argumentVoteYes':function(currentArgumentId){
    check(currentArgumentId,Match._id); // will error if not an _id

    var post = Arguments.findOne({ _id: currentArgumentId });
    var userId = Meteor.userId(); // the current user

    if ( post && userId ){ // make sure a real user is operating on an actual document
      // only update if no votes have been recorded OR
      // user hasn't already voted

      if ( !post.votedUp || post.votedUp.indexOf(userId) === -1 ){ 
        Arguments.update(currentArgumentId, {
          $pull: { votedDown: userId },
          $inc: { score: 2 },
          $addToSet: {votedUp: userId }
        });
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Hey Michel! I tried your suggestion and it worked for me if i use `userId = Meteor.userId();` why didnt it worked with `var userId = this.userId();`??? Thank you for your help!

Comment: If i try to implement the same logic for my second call `argumentVoteYesElse` i am getting a `Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined` error. Guess its cause i didnt insert votedUp when creating a new post??. When someone is clicking the first time of a new post and wants to vote this post up, the error message occures. So there is no votedUp while trying to post.votedUp.indexOf(userId). What shall i do now?? I have added the vote Down buttons for the post now. Same problem if clicking first time on voteDown and then change to voteUp.

Comment: The Problem is now with my logic i guess. Because now i am able to call in my console `'voteUpYes'`. My score increments 2 and `votedUp:Meteor.userId()` is set. After this i could call `'voteYesElseElse'` and decrement the counter 1 and `votedUp: Meteor.userId()` is removed. Then i could call `'voteUpYes'` again and so on. There would be no limit.. This problem is really messing me up. =/

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you with that beyond noting that you need symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for whether the user is in the votedUp/down arrays on the server.  You have the logic right client side, so just apply the same logic before you do the actual update on the server.

Comment: yes but i dont know how to get the array value of the Meteor.userId()? something like db.arguments.find({_id:currentArgumentId......?}); I have to check the array if the Meteor.userId(); already exists but how do i get the values? i tried something like  `var votedUpMeteorUser = Arguments.findOne(currentArgumentId);
    if (Meteor.userId()!=null && votedUpMeteorUser.votedUp != Meteor.userId())` {.....} but this doesnt work

Comment: You should use this.userId on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the same thing before and I found the solution in just using an array of userId's which you don't pass from client side (you just save current user's ID) and count total IDs in the array. It doesn't add the same ID twice.

From my code (you can do the rest of the checks like if the user is in disliker array, do something etc.):

```
likeActivity: function (activityId) {
    Activities.update(activityId,{
        $addToSet: {
            likers: this.userId,
        }
    });
},

unlikeActivity: function (activityId) {
    Activities.update(activityId,{
        $pull: {
            likers: this.userId,
        }
    })
}
```

In my helper:

```
likeCount: function() {
    return this.likers.length
}
```